# yum Proxy connection failed: 407 on redhat 6.5

Tags: redhat, yum

I keep getting yum proxy connection failed error 407 even though it seems like yum is able to successfully reach the proxy.

I have log from running yum below with highest debug and error to do `list packages` command:

```
# yum -d 10 -e 10 --rpmverbosity debug --enablerepo=\* list packages
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "product-id" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Loading "subscription-manager" plugin
Running "config" handler for "security" plugin
Running "config" handler for "subscription-manager" plugin
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Proxy connection failed: 407
Config time: 0.202
Yum Version: 3.2.29
COMMAND: yum -d 10 -e 10 --rpmverbosity debug --enablerepo=* list packages
Installroot: /
Ext Commands:

   packages
Setting up Package Sacks
epel-debuginfo/metalink                                                                                                                                   | 2.4 kB     00:00
epel-debuginfo                                                                                                                                            | 3.0 kB     00:00
epel-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                                                                                 | 675 kB     00:00
epel-source/metalink                                                                                                                                      | 2.4 kB     00:00
epel-source                                                                                                                                               | 3.5 kB     00:00
epel-source/primary_db                                                                                                                                    | 1.8 MB     00:00
epel-testing/metalink                                                                                                                                     | 3.0 kB     00:00
Using older repomd.xml
  Latest: Sat May  6 05:04:26 2017
  Using: Fri May  5 22:12:48 2017
epel-testing                                                                                                                                              | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel-testing/primary_db                                                                                                                                   | 362 kB     00:00
epel-testing-debuginfo/metalink                                                                                                                           | 3.0 kB     00:00
epel-testing-debuginfo                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB     00:00
epel-testing-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                                                                         |  22 kB     00:00
epel-testing-source/metalink                                                                                                                              | 3.0 kB     00:00
epel-testing-source                                                                                                                                       | 3.5 kB     00:00
epel-testing-source/primary_db                                                                                                                            |  90 kB     00:00
rhel-source                                                                                                                                               | 2.6 kB     00:00 ...
rhel-source/primary_db                                                                                                                                    | 2.0 MB     00:04 ...
rhel-source-beta                                                                                                                                          | 1.3 kB     00:00 ...
rhel-source-beta/primary                                                                                                                                  |  214 B     00:00 ...
rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo                                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                                                               |  16 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-source                                                                                                                             | 3.0 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-source/primary_db                                                                                                                  |  30 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing                                                                                                                            | 3.6 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing/primary_db                                                                                                                 | 1.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-debuginfo                                                                                                                  | 3.0 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                                                       | 1.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-source                                                                                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing-source/primary_db                                                                                                          | 1.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo                                                                                                                       | 3.0 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                                                            | 4.9 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-source                                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-source/primary_db                                                                                                               | 7.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing                                                                                                                         | 3.6 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing/primary_db                                                                                                              | 1.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing-debuginfo                                                                                                               | 3.0 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                                                    | 1.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing-source                                                                                                                  | 2.9 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing-source/primary_db                                                                                                       | 1.3 kB     00:00
webtatic-archive                                                                                                                                          | 2.9 kB     00:00
webtatic-archive/primary_db                                               92% [===========================================================     ] 343 kB/s | 2.3 MB     00:00 ETA
```

Is it ok ignore this error? Is yum impacted in its functionality somehow, and if so, how should I fix it?

I have already configured the proxy properly via environment variables (http_proxy, ftp_proxy, etc) and also via `/etc/yum.conf`

I know the proxy configuration is correct because yum is able to do list packages as above. And there is even a progress bar reflecting for the download.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the environmnet variables for proxy / yum.conf proxy entries etc and entering the proxy details in /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf .